# Use column name in regex in pandas

Tags: regex, pandas

I use:

```
df[df['A'].astype(str).str.contains("^XYZ|^$", regex=True)]
```

to select rows where the value in column A starts with a pattern ('XYZ') or is an empty string. I need to use the value of another column (e.g. column 'B') instead of XYZ. How is it possible to include the name of this column in the regex? Is it even possible?

Comment: You will need to use `df.apply` here.

Comment: its best if you `zip()` the 2 columns and then use the seaond element to find in the first one.  `df[[ yourregexsearchwith_a_and_b  for a, b in zip(df['A'],df['B'])]]` also look at f-strings if needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution is to use [`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) with [`DataFrame.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```py
import pandas as pd
import re
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'A':['XYZ won the match.', '', 'ZYX lost.'],
     'B':['XYZ', 'WORD', 'BAC']
    })
df[df.apply(lambda row: bool(re.search(fr"^{re.escape(row['B'])}|^$", row['A'])), axis=1)]
## If the values in Column B are valid regexps:
# df[df.apply(lambda row: bool(re.search(fr"^{row['B']}|^$", row['A'])), axis=1)]
```

Output:

```
                    A     B
0  XYZ won the match.   XYZ
1                      WORD
```

Note the `fr"^{re.escape(row['B'])}|^$` part build the pattern dynamically from the `row['B']` values and all special chars in the string are escaped with `re.escape` to avoid regex matching issue. You do not need `re.escape` if the values in Column B are valid regular expressions.

Comment: @Marc If your pattern is going to remain the same, you may write it a bit more efficiently like ``fr"^(?:{re.escape(row['B'])}|$)"``